# How can we prove that $x\Gamma(x)=1.$

Tags: calculus, mathematica

how can we prove that, for $x$ real and positive, $lim_{x→0^+}$ $x\Gamma(x)=1.$

Comment: $z\Gamma (z)={\frac {z\pi }{\sin (\pi z) \Gamma (1-z) } }$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @MarekKryspin You don't even need to go that far... $$z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$$